# python list __iter__ method called on every loop?

Tags: python, iterator, loops, python-2.6

I am trying to make a class which inherits from a python list. I want the elements of the list to be initialized/finalized with every loop of the list. I thought this could be done by overriding the `__iter__` method of the python list but I can't seem to get it to work. The `__iter__` method appears to called only once ? (see below)

```
class MyList(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        print 'do something'
        return list.__iter__(self)

my_list = MyList(range(10))
print my_list

for item in my_list:
    print item
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
do something
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Any idea how I can achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 12):

You can simply return a generator expression from `__iter__()`

```
class MyList(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        return (self.do_something(x) for x in list.__iter__(self))

    def do_something(self, x):
        print 'do something', x
        return x

my_list = MyList(range(10))
print my_list

for item in my_list:
    print item
```

ncoghlan suggests using a generator in place of the generator expression which makes for easier debugging

```
class MyList(list):

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in list.__iter__(self):
            yield self.do_something(x)

    def do_something(self, x):
        print 'do something', x
        return x

my_list = MyList(range(10))
print my_list

for item in my_list:
    print item
```

alternatively you could use imap here

```
from itertools import imap

class MyList(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        return imap(self.do_something, list.__iter__(self))

    def do_something(self, x):
        print 'do something', x
        return x


my_list = MyList(range(10))
print my_list

for item in my_list:
    print item
```

Comment: I was going to vote this up, but why return a generator expression instead of just implementing a generator?

Comment: @Winston, I'm not calling `obj.__iter__`, i'm calling `list.__iter__` it's necessary to do it that way to avoid endless recursion

Comment: @ncoghlan, why would you implement a generator where a GE can suffice?

Comment: You get much better debugging information when a generator function goes wrong (since it knows its own name). A GE is useful if you specifically need an expression, but if you're defining a named function anyway, then it is better to actually make that a generator function:
`def __iter__(self):
   for x in list.__iter__(self):
     yield self.do_something(x)` (oh, for vertical whitespace in comments...)

Comment: @ncoghlan, OK I've added it to my answer so you don't have to lose sleep about whitespace in comments

Comment: Thanks :)

It may also be an artefact of already knowing Python before GEs were added. For a very long time writing a generator function was simply *the* way to write `__iter__` methods if there wasn't an existing iterator with the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

`__iter__` returns an [iterator object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter). If you need to do something in every iteration, you have to implement your own (it has to implement two methods described in the linked docs).

Answer (score 3):

The python class `__iter__()` method actually returns an iterator object.
See the following for reference: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types

On the iterator object the `next()` method will be called on each step of the loop. You could write a custom iterator which would be returned by your custom list.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the elements of the list to be initialized/finalized with every loop of the list

A list has no direct control over this. Several loops can access a list in parallel (e.g. in nested loops). Each loop is controlled by an *iterator*, and `__iter__()` should return iterators, every time it's called. You can't return the same iterator instance all the time, because said parallel loops will then interfere with each other.

But inside an iterator you're free to instantiate items as you need. Finalizing them from inside the iterator is hardly wise, because once you returned an item, you lost control over it. If you finalize it at a later moment, outer code that still relies on the item may fail. If you need to finalize your items, make it a responsibility of items' consumer.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but what you've already been told is true. `next()` is the method called in every iteration.

```
class MyList(list):
    def next(self):
        print "Do something"
        return list.next(self)
```

(I didn't tested it)

Comment: would you please be more specific?

Comment: next will never be called on the list object. You have to define an __iter__ method which returns an iterator object. The next method will be called on that returned iterator object.